# How to populate new column starting from 400000 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I'm working on a homework for college, i need to set values to a new created column but it must start from a specific number, in this case 40000000, so it will be something like this:

```
ID ║ Column to populate ║ FirstName ║ LastName ║
1     40000000             John        Smith
2     40000001             John        Walker
3     40000002             John        Locke
and etc...
```

I guess it's something related to the following query:

**UPDATE** [table_name] **SET** [column_name] = [column_name] + 1;

But this clearly won't start from the number i want.

Maybe it's a dumb question, but i googled it and i couldn't find anything related to what i need, so any help is really appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can alter the table that you created add the column as auto_increment type and then ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=40000000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option using window functions:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from mytable t1
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.new_col = 3999 + t1.rn
```

Just in case: if `id` starts at `1` and increments without gaps, then it is even simpler:

```
update mytable set new_col = 3999 + id
```

I don't think this is safe, though: `id` looks like an `auto_increment` column, and such column does not guarantee no gap.

Comment: Excellent !! I did the second one and it worked like a charm! I don't know how i didn't think about that, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

And you want there to be no gaps in the numbers?  It will be folly to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Virtually any `INSERT` that has any kind of hiccup will "burn" a number, thereby leaving a gap.

Hence, you cannot assume `AUTO_INCREMENT` will provide any kind of clean sequence of numbers.

If you don't care about gaps, then `ALTER TABLE t AUTO_INCREMENT=40000000` is a simple way for *future* inserts to be at least that big.  But there could be gaps.

Perhaps less than one table in 10,000 plays that game.  So, I respectfully suggest, that it is a useless exercise for someone learning MySQL/MariaDB.